# Prevent pandas concat'ting my dataframes both vertically and horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am trying to concat two dataframes, horizontally. `df2` contains 2 result variables for every observation in `df1`.

```
df1.shape 
(242583, 172)
df2.shape
(242583, 2)
```

My code is:

```
Fin = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis= 1)
```

But somehow the result is stacked in 2 dimensions:

```
Fin.shape
(485166, 174)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Both index(row) and the column indexes are different.  pandas does intrinsic data alignment.  Meaning that mostly all operations that are done between two dataframes are aligned on indexes.  Hence, you combined dataframe is an addition of the dataframes in both number of rows (records) and columns, because there is no overlap in indexes. See @jezrael solution for an example.

Comment: **Because your indexes mismatch**. As others said. You can still do `pd.concat(..., ignore_index=True)`, it should prevent the unwanted vertical concatenation. But you should probably fix up your indices like people are recommending.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are different index values, so indexes are not aligned and get `NaN`s:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a','a','a'],
    'B': range(3)
})
print (df1)
   A  B
0  a  0
1  a  1
2  a  2

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'C': ['b','b','b'],
    'D': range(4,7)
}, index=[5,7,8])
print (df2)
   C  D
5  b  4
7  b  5
8  b  6
```

---

```
Fin = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis= 1)
print (Fin)
     A    B    C    D
0    a  0.0  NaN  NaN
1    a  1.0  NaN  NaN
2    a  2.0  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN    b  4.0
7  NaN  NaN    b  5.0
8  NaN  NaN    b  6.0
```

One possible solution is create default indexes:

```
Fin = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis= 1)
print (Fin)
   A  B  C  D
0  a  0  b  4
1  a  1  b  5
2  a  2  b  6
```

Or assign:

```
df2.index = df1.index
Fin = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis= 1)
print (Fin)
   A  B  C  D
0  a  0  b  4
1  a  1  b  5
2  a  2  b  6

df1.index = df2.index
Fin = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis= 1)
print (Fin)
   A  B  C  D
5  a  0  b  4
7  a  1  b  5
8  a  2  b  6
```

Comment: I was writing up an answer but this beat me to it! One thing I would add is if you are struggling with merging data in dataframes or series, the [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) have a visual guide on different merge strategies.

Comment: @Nathan - be free add it to my answer ;)

Comment: I looked into the visual guide, but they only specify the axis. I wasn't aware that the indexing causes this problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the one-liner, there is the `set_index` method:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["a"] * 3, 'B': range(3)})
y = pd.DataFrame({'C': ["b"] * 3, 'D': range(4,7)})
pd.concat([x, y.set_index(x.index)], axis = 1)
```

Note that `pd.concat([x, y], axis = 1)` will instead create new lines and produce NA values, due to non-matching indexes, as shown by @jezrael