# Pandas concatenate Multiindex columns with same row index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multi-index

I want to concatenate the multidimensional output of a NumPy computation matching in dimensions the shape of the input (with regards to rows and respective selected columns).
But it fails with: `NotImplementedError: Can only union MultiIndex with MultiIndex or Index of tuples, try mi.to_flat_index().union(other) instead`.

I do not want to flatten the indices first - so is there another way to get it to work?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

df = pd.DataFrame({('metrik_0', Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')): {(1, 1): 2.5393693602911447, (1, 5): 4.316896324314225, (1, 6): 4.271001191238499, (1, 9): 2.8712588011247377, (1, 11): 4.0458495954752545}, ('metrik_0', Timestamp('2020-01-01 01:00:00')): {(1, 1): 4.02779063729038, (1, 5): 3.3849606155101224, (1, 6): 4.284114856052976, (1, 9): 3.980919941298365, (1, 11): 5.042488191587525}, ('metrik_0', Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:00:00')): {(1, 1): 2.374592085569529, (1, 5): 3.3405503781564487, (1, 6): 3.4049690284720366, (1, 9): 3.892686173978996, (1, 11): 2.1876998087043127}})

def compute_return_columns_to_df(df, colums_to_process,axis=0):
    method = 'compute_result'
    renamed_base_levels = map(lambda x: f'{x}_{method}', colums_to_process.get_level_values(0).unique())
    renamed_columns = colums_to_process.set_levels(renamed_base_levels, level=0)

    #####
    # perform calculation in numpy here
    # for the sake of simplicity (and as the actual computation is irrelevant - it is omitted in this minimal example)
    result = df[colums_to_process].values
    #####
    
    result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=renamed_columns)
    display(result)    
    return pd.concat([df, result], axis=1) # fails with: NotImplementedError: Can only union MultiIndex with MultiIndex or Index of tuples, try mi.to_flat_index().union(other) instead.

# I do not want to flatten the indices first - so is there another way to get it to work?

compute_return_columns_to_df(df[df.columns[0:3]].head(), df.columns[0:2])
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277682/python-pandas-concat-vertical-and-horizontal I just want to add it as columns. It would certainly be possible to iterate all the columns and add it  - but I would prefer to add ll the columns at once to the source data frame.

Comment: I.e. for col in result.columns:
        df[col] = result[col]
    return df certainly works. But requires to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code failed is in:

```
result = df[colums_to_process].values
result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=renamed_columns)
```

Note that *result* has:

- column names with the top index level renamed to
  *metrik_0_compute_result* (so far OK),
- but the **row index** is the default **single level** index,
  composed of consecutive numbers.

Then, when you concatenate *df* and *result*, *Pandas* attempts to
align both source DataFrames on the row index, but they are incompatible
(*df* has a MultiIndex, whereas *result* has an "ordinary" index).

Change this part of your code to:

```
result = df[colums_to_process]
result.columns = renamed_columns
```

This way *result* keeps the original index and *concat* raises no
exception.

Another remark: Your function contains *axis* parameter, which is
never used. Consider removing it.

## Another possible approach

Since *result* has a default (single level) index, you can leave the
previous part of code as is, but reset the index in *df* before joining:

```
return pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True), result], axis=1)
```

This way both DataFrames have the same indices and you can concatenate
them as well.

Comment: This does not work - as I said the operation is working on numpy (= implicitly the original index of pandas is deleted). So you are right - but unfortunately, the outline solution only works here in the simple pandas based dummy example.