# Concatenating and appending of DFs results in twice the amount of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, data-science

I want to concatenate two dataframes that have the shape
(261, 35) and (600,35). I expect in the end to get a df with the shape (861,35) but I get (861, 70). I used the following methods

```
dfs = [df1,df2]
conc_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

and

```
df1.append(df2)
```

However I always get double the amount of columns. Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: A sample of your dfs would be nice...

Comment: if the dataframes have different column names, then that is the expected behavior

Comment: That was it, thanks Asish!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas: concat vertical and horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277682/python-pandas-concat-vertical-and-horizontal)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the two data frame name same

```
df1.columns = df2.columns

conc_df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Comment: Yes, that was the reason, thanks BENY!